# Use tar.gz file like a folder?

Tags: php, tar

Does PHP have an extension that permits to use a tar.gz like a folder?

I have some file that uses a similar structure and I don't need to extract all to read information about it, so can I make `file_get_contents("my/path/to/tar/something.tar.gz/out.json");`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PHP's [Phar](http://php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php) extension. For an introduction, see [PHP: Using Phar Archives: Introduction](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.using.intro.php).

```
file_get_contents("phar://my/path/to/tar/something.tar.gz/out.json");
```

If you don't already have Phar, you can install the [PHP_Archive package](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Archive) or use the [PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/phar).